# Displaying images from mysql database - php

Tags: php

I am currently having problems with displaying image from mysql database. I am able to upload an image to mysql database, however if i want to retrieve it from the database, it is displayed in Gibberish text.

**Here is upload.php**

```
  if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) {

  $filename = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_FILES['image']['name']);
  $tmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
  $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
  $data = addslashes($data);
  fclose($fp);

  $query = "INSERT INTO `TABLES` (`image`)
           VALUES( NULL,'$data')";
  $result = $mysqli->query($query);
}
```

**View.php**

```
 $mysqlquery = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
 $results = $mysqli->query($mysqlquery);

 if($results->num_rows > 0){
 while ($row = $results ->fetch_assoc()){
 echo '<div align = "center">';
 echo "<b>".$row["image"]. "<br></b>";
 header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use img src for `echo "<b>".$row["image"]. "<br></b>";`

Comment: Yeah i heard you have to use that but im not sure what goes inside img src

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375302/using-imagejpeg-to-save-serve-image-file).

Comment: Try `echo "<img src=".$row["image"]. "><br>";` and get rid of the header.

Comment: Fred -ii-  Its still showing gibberish text

Comment: Can you post an example data of what's in the `image` column?

Comment: image column from the database ? its a blob type

Answer (score 0):

Try this and do not forget to give image path before source

```
echo "<img src='your image location directory/". $row['image'] .'" >";
```

Comment: is the image directory, the location of where the image is currently stored ?

Answer (score 0):

Oooooh... I just ***wish*** I had the answer to this one...

Some thoughts, though.

First, from personal experience I urge against storing images in the database. For one thing, your database backups will quickly become ridiculous. A more common, and better, approach is to store the images in the file system and store only the location *(e.g. /img/pic03.jpg )* of the image in the database.

Next, I see you are modifying the received binary data:

```
$tmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$data = addslashes($data);
fclose($fp);
```

Perhaps you know something that I don't (it's not difficult), but generally, if you gerfingerpoke with binary image data you get ... um... *gibberish*.    **Try disabling those lines and see what happens.**